# Disable Bootstrap transitions for Jasmine test

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jasmine

I am attempting to write a Jasmine test to cover a Twitter Boostrap modal dialog.  The test fails when the debugger line is commented out. It passes when processing is paused by the debugger and I continue.  I believe the transitions in Bootstrap modal are causing the issue because the modal dialog is not yet in the DOM at the time of my expect call.

How can I disable transitions during my tests?

Thanks

```
describe("test dialog", function(){
    it("when cancel button is clicked", function() {
        spyOn(MyTestObj, 'myMethod')

        $("#cancelButton").click();

        debugger;

        expect($(".bootbox-body")).toHaveText("Are you sure you want to cancel?")

        $('.modal-footer button[data-bb-handler="Yes"]').click();

        expect(MyTestObj.myMethod).toHaveBeenCalledWith("123")
    })
})
```

Thanks Jarred, your solution worked great!  Here is my working test:

```
    describe("test dialog", function(){
        it("when cancel button is clicked", function() {
            spyOn(MyTestObj, 'myMethod')

            $("#cancelButton").click();

            waitsFor(function() {
                return $(".bootbox-body").is(":visible");
            }, "Element did not show up", 1000);

            runs(function () {
                expect($(".bootbox-body")).toHaveText("Are you sure you want to cancel?")
                $('.modal-footer button[data-bb-handler="Yes"]').click();

                expect(MyTestObj.myMethod).toHaveBeenCalledWith("123")
            })
        })      
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `waitsFor` jasmine method followed by a `runs` block (https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Asynchronous-specs#waitsforfunction-optional-message-optional-timeout):

`$('.modal-footer button[data-bb-handler="Yes"]').click();`

```
waitsFor(function() {
    return $(".bootbox-body").is(":visible");
}, "Element did not show up", 1000);

runs(function () {
    expect(MyTestObj.myMethod).toHaveBeenCalledWith("123")
})
```